# How can I efficiently jump to a specific time in a large log?

Tags: less-unix

I have a huge daily textual logs (2-3 GB), which I want to investigate for specific event (which I know when it occurred), I'm using `less` (since it all on ssh to remote server).

I'm looking for an option to jump as fast as I can to the exact time, and I think if there is an option to a binary search to find it, it should be the fastest (right now jump to end of the day takes tens of seconds)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [other question's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/701237/657490):
**sgrep** might work for you:

```
sudo apt-get install sgrep
sgrep -l '"needle"' haystack.txt
```

The project page http://sgrep.sourceforge.net/ says:

> Sgrep uses a binary search algorithm, which is very fast, but requires sorted input.